# how to render a javascript files after a view is render in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-routing

I am new to angular and this is first time working with angular.js . I am trying to build an single page application in angular which has the following pages

1. Index.html - which is main page for all rendering
2. Home page - holds the content of home page
3. some more pages

All my pages have jquery script to handle modal popup form submission etc.

All of them work, but when i render those pages with `ng-view` inside index.html. Those script doesn't work,. They do not render as well.

Can anyone please tell me how can i fix this issue or if there is any other way of doing the same keeping those jquery functions.

Here is my file structure
**Index.html**

```
<html>
......
<header>
   <script src="<ANGULAR.JS>"></script>
   <script src="<ANGULAR ROUTE.JS"></script>
   <script src="<JQUERY>"></script>
   <script defer src="<OTHER SCRIPTS>"></script>
</header>
<body>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
<div>
   <LOTS OF HTML CONTENTS>
</div>
<script src="<PATH TO JS FILE>"></script>
```

Comment: Did jquery imported first b4 angular?

Comment: No i imported jquery after anguler in the header

Comment: Try to switch the two if thats going to work

Comment: Now its working, do know how this happen though. Thank you a lot :))

Comment: Your angularjs  loaded your html files through "ng-view" without jquery on it that is why your jquery script on it is having issue, remember jquery and angular is different modules they dont share the same scope

Comment: oh okay thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

Switching places of angular with jQuery fixed the issue as suggested by @arnold thanks a lot :)